# DEBUG compiler if reference is opposite to what is expected

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5

I have a couple of debug statements that I've wrapped with compiler references.

```
#if DEBUG
    Debug.WriteLine("Debug statement");
#endif
```

However when in the Debug configuration, DEBUG seems to equal false, and in Release DEBUG seems to equal true.

This is only happening in what looks like a single project, I am successfully getting debug statements from other projects.

Here is what I think the relevant part of the .csproj file is

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Which to me looks perfectly fine, yet I still have this odd behaviour.

Comment: No, that looks good.  You are definitely helping to much, Debug.WriteLine() already has a [Conditional] attribute that ensures it only works when DEBUG is defined.

Comment: This isn't C++, DEBUG is neither true nor false (it has no *value*), it's either defined or not defined.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Right so I don't need to double wrap it, however DEBUG certainly doesn't seem to be defined despite it being defined in by configuration?

Comment: Right, so what are the odds that the code has an #undef or #define to screw you up?  Clean it up, you'll encounter them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so the problem was that I was checking against the settings for the x86 platform (which had the DEBUG constants defined).

I was then building against the AnyCPU platform which didn't have them defined.

Completely my fault...